# RMarkdown / Knitr: Hide code for Word document, but code folding in HTML document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

For a project, I would like the knitr-output when choosing for a HTML to enable code folding, but to hide all code when knitting a word document.

My current RMarkdown YAML:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "me"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    code_folding: hide
    number_sections: false
  word_document:
    reference_docx: reference.docx
    # Option to hide code in word document?
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
bibliography: references.bib  
link-citations: yes
editor_options:
  markdown:
    wrap: 72
linestretch: 2
lang: en
---
```

Is there an option for the `word_document` YAML-tag to make this possible? Or another workaround or package? If you set `echo=FALSE` or `include=FALSE` in the R chuncks, then this also omits the code in the HTML document. Looked around in [RMarkdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html) and different forums, but can't find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `knitr::is_html_output` to check whether you are rendering to HTML or not. This could then be used to conditionally set `echo=FALSE` for non-HTML output:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "me"
output:
  word_document:
    # Option to hide code in word document?
    #reference_docx: reference.docx
  bookdown::html_document2:
    code_folding: hide
    number_sections: false
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r include=FALSE}
if (!knitr::is_html_output()) knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
```

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

##### Word Output

[image]

##### HTML Output

[image]